# How to set DateFormat in mvc3 as "Jan/01/2012" in Controller not in Viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors, c#-3.0

My code is :

```
DateTime fdate = DateTime.ParseExact(collection["txtToDate"], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime tdate = DateTime.ParseExact(collection["txtFromDate"], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


DateTime fromDate =Convert.ToDateTime( String.Format("{0:MMM/dd/yyyy}",fdate));
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0:MMM/dd/yyyy}", tdate));
```

but in this code dates appear as "01/jan/2012" and I want them to appear as "Jan/01/2012"

How can I fix this?

Comment: In what code? How/where are you displaying this date?

Comment: i want to Display date in Database as this format...

Comment: ACtually i want to show generalledger report and i want to display date in format"Jan/01/2012"..

Comment: You don't display in a database. You store data in it. What is `generalledger report`? Can you provide an example of how you are building this report?

Comment: how to Store date in it as format " Jan/01/2012". i m enable to convert it in this format...so tell me solution.

Comment: Why care about a format in your database? You shouldn't use any format. You should store dates in `datetime` columns. I hope you are not using `varchar` columns in your database to store dates. It is only when you want to display this date somewhere that you may start caring about formatting.

Comment: yes..i not use varchar..i use datetime.....i just want to Show that my fromdate variable show datefromat as "jan/01/2012". so tell me how this is possible by conversion.

Comment: you are not answering my questions. I already asked you and I repeat my question for the last time: where do you want to show this date? What code are you currently using to show it?

Comment: @LakhbirChandel: Your question is very unclear because the code you list does not appear to display a DateTime at all.  Each line is converting some string into a DateTime.

Comment: DateTime t = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["txtToDate"]);
            IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
            DateTime dtfrmdate = DateTime.Parse(collection["txtToDate"], provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `DateTime` object into a string like "Jan/01/2012":

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
string formattedDateString = myDateTime.ToString("MMM/dd/yyyy");
```

To convert a string of the format "Jan/01/2012" back into a `DateTime` object (to store in your database, for example):

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(collection["txtToDate"], "MMM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i use this code but it occur error"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."...

Comment: @LakhbirChandel: You are not providing enough information.  If that was the error you received, than the string was not, in fact, in the format this code will parse.  The second code I listed here will parse dates formatted as "Jan/01/2012".  It will not parse any other format.  If you expect any more help you need to be more clear about what you are trying to do.  What, exactly, was the text you were attempting to parse?

Comment: Thank u very much sir...at finally i  find my solution with the help of your Code " string formattedDateString = myDateTime.ToString("MMM/dd/yyyy"); " Thanks Again...